# find url in html using regex

Tags: javascript, html, regex, url, uri

I know there's plenty of stuff about it online but I'm trying to overcome a specific problem I've not encountered anyone asking about it.

So I have this regex I built for searching urls inside href/src attributes:

```
\s(?:href|src)\s*=\s*(["']??)\s*([^"']+)(?:\s*\1)[^>]*>
```

Problem is that it's matching things like this as well:

```
var a="";
a += "<a  href=\""+d.y+"\">";
```

I've tried to come up with a solution on how not get these false positives but I couldn't really so I'm asking for help here.

*Note that I'm not looking for parsing the dom in-order to do it, only regex*

Comment: Are you learning regular expressions? I think you should also learn when to use and when to avoid them. You have HTML, use a DOM parser to get the data out from the HTML document.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm using regex because I'm finding more urls with other regex outside of href/src attributes otherwise impossible to find with dom parsers, this is just a regex I'm planning to put in a 'discover' regex array of urls that will be fetched from html/css/js/other files. that's why I use regex

Comment: Then please make it clear in the question, what you are doing, using what tools, and not just *searching urls inside href/src attributes*

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It'll just add noise to the question, I don't seek for help on how to make the other regex for finding other urls, all I'm asking is targeted question about a specific regex and on how not to get false positives from it. The ultimate goal has nothing to do with the question really

Comment: Just to show you how to get src and hrefs using dom manipulation: `window.onload=function() {
  var srcs = document.querySelectorAll('[src]');
  var hrefs = document.querySelectorAll('[href]');
  console.log(srcs,hrefs)
} ` https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/vdbvtsy4/

Answer (score 0):

I ended up rewriting the regex making it to expect 0 or more attributes followed by the src/href attribute so false positives like the one in my questions won't count.

Here's my new regex:

```
\s(?:src|href)\s*=\s*(?:["']?\s*([^"'>]+)\s*["']?)(?:\s+[^"'>\s]+(?:\s*=\s*["']?[^"'>]*["']?)?)*\s*\/?>
```